# Javascript is not executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, unobtrusive-javascript

i cant figure out, why my javascript is not executed (and its really not executed).

/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```js
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

/app/controllers/project_controller.rb:

```rb
def upload
    @projects = Project.all.order(updated_at: :desc)
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js {render layout: false}
    end
end
```

/app/views/projects/show.html.erb:

```rb
<%= link_to project_upload_path, :project => @project.id, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
    Upload &nbsp;
    <%= glyph("plus") %>
<% end %>
```

/app/views/projects/upload.html.erb:

```rb
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>Upload File to <%= @project.name %> project</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <%= render :partial => "uploadform", :action => "savefile" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

/app/views/projects/_uploadform.html.erb:

```rb
<%= form_for :upload, url: {action: "savefile"}, :multipart => true  do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:project_id, :value => params[:id]) %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, input_html: { hidden: true }, label: 'Upload Attachment'  %>
    <input id="file-display" class="input-large uneditable-input" type="text">
    <%= f.submit "Save File", :class => "btn btn-default btn-file", :id => "upload-btn" %>
<% end %>
```

/app/views/projects/upload.js.erb:

```js
$(document).on('ajax:success', function() {
    alert("Test");
});
```

I tried everything. I added and removed "{render layout: false}" in my controller. I tried "page:change" and "turbolinks:load" in my upload.js.erb (instead of "ajax:success"). I tried all of the Java-Ready functions in "_uploadform.js.erb" (instead of "upload.js.erb"). I tried "remote: true" in link_to (show.html.erb) - but then it only executes js.erb (just the alert came up). I also updated Rails from 4.2.1 to 4.2.7.1 and tried "//= require jquery.turbolinks" in application.js (with all the document ready functions above).

As you can see in my log, it seems that it doesnt respond with the Javascript:

```
Started GET "/projects/upload/20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-05 14:05:48 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#upload as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"20"}
  Project Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 20]]
  Rendered projects/_uploadform.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered projects/upload.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 327ms (Views: 324.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Please help me. I dont understand why this is not working in any way.

Comment: I don't think there is an `ajax:success` selector. Did you mean `$(document).ajaxSuccess`

Comment: No. I dont know where i get that, but it doesnt work with "turbolinks:load" nor "page:change", too. So, yes, maybe "ajax:success" is wrong, but the other selectors doesnt work too.

Comment: I don't know if it has any difference, but try to load `jquery_ujs` after `jquery` in your `application.js`

Comment: no, sadly that didnt helped (even tough i just loaded jquery after jquery_ujs (because in my opinion i already loaded jquery_ujs after jquery)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell rails to execute the post of the form via JavaScript. In the log you can see the PagesController is rendering HTML and not JS

`Processing by ProjectsController#upload as HTML`

Try adding :remote => true to your form_for helper

`<%= form_for :upload, url: {action: "savefile"}, :multipart => true, :remote => true  do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:project_id, :value => params[:id]) %>
    <%= f.file_field :file, input_html: { hidden: true }, label: 'Upload Attachment'  %>
    <input id="file-display" class="input-large uneditable-input" type="text">
    <%= f.submit "Save File", :class => "btn btn-default btn-file", :id => "upload-btn" %>
<% end %>`

See the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for for more information.

Comment: Sadly this does not work, too. I also tried to move things from "upload.js.erb" to "_uploadform.js.erb" - but in the logs, i can see, that its still rendered in HTML instead of JS even though i have data-remote="true" in HTML of my form. Any other Ideas?

Comment: I found out, that if i set "defaults: {:format => 'js'} " in my routes.rb, that i have to create an exception from Forgery (protect_from_forgery except: :upload", because of an error: "Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.") and then the JS is just shown in the Browser as an Text File.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to upload files with an AJAX request, requiring the :multipart => true and :remote => true for your form definition.

File uploads can't be done using remote, however this issue is easily resolved by making use of Remotipart gem - it enables AJAX file uploads without any further changes to your code.

1. Add **gem 'remotipart'** to your Gemfile
2. Add **//= require jquery.remotipart** to application.js (after jquery_ujs)
3. Use **remote: true** and **multipart: true** in your form declaration

You should now be able to asynchronously upload files.

For further information check out https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Comment: Actually i try to use Boostrap Design for the Filebrowser Button. Is it not possible to have a Javascript (to do whatever after the page is loaded) in this situation?

Comment: Well that's exactly what the remotipart gives you. I updated my answer with clearer instructions

Comment: Thanks you, but its not working as i expected. Maybe i was unclear what iam trying to accomplish. I would like to execute a javascript when my view with my "file browse"-button (the view with the form_for on it) is finished loading - not after i uploaded something. Even with remotipart, my javascript is not executed at that point.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to render the upload form AND run the code in upload.js.erb. Rails doesn't work like that. upload.js.erb is rendered as a result of an AJAX call to the upload action of the controller and upload.html.erb is rendered as a result of an HTML call to the upload action of the controller (not both). Your link in show.html.erb is a straight forward html invocation and therefore upload is responding by rendering upload.html.erb. If you want to invoke (jquery) on page load simply embed $(document).ready( function() {...}); in a <script> tag in the html.erb file

Comment: In this case, i think, i was misled by some tutorials in the past - i tought, inline-scripts where a bad idea and not the rails way. And of course, with that its working. Thanks a lot!